# Parsing a very long JSON file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using a Nuxt App that has it's own Express based API, it looks to be working fine, but I'm scared of overusing someone else's services.

And I found a JSON that has everything I need to deliver before-hand.

The problem is, that it is 4MB long, and I don't think it would be a very efficient progress to retrieve and add data from it.

If I want to efficiently parse a huge JSON, and use it for the server (As in, to serve parts of it according to the requests I receive).

How would you go around it? Any ideas?

Comment: If that 4MB of data isn't going to change, I'd probably do a one-time batch job to load it and store in in a database. Then whenever user requests come in, just use your DB

Comment: JSON is quite inefficient for adding new data to it because without some hacks, you have to read the whole thing into memory, parse it, add to it, stringify it and write it back out.  It's just not a good format for incrementally adding to it.  For text formats, CSV is trivially to add new lines to.  Otherwise, you just want to use a database.

Answer (score 1):

Is only 4MB, you should just load it to memory, any other thing you want to do probably is overkill, literally, fs.readFile, then JSON.parse, that's it, in memory.

Trying to come up with a more sophisticated and "efficient" way on this context is probably not worth the trouble and maybe is just not posible, if you end up using another service just to store and manage those 4mb of data, the IO needed for that is orders of magnitude more than just keeping it on ram.